# Match fields in two different Excel Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

So I have one Excel file with multiple sheets in it, how can I match fields from say sheet1 column A and sheet2 column B if the names match add name to sheet3?

Basically I have Students in Sheet1 and Sheet2 with different criteria, however I want to find duplicates from Sheet1 and Sheet2 and throw those duplicates on Sheet3.

Also similar question:
How can I find Name in Column B and Change that value to something else in Column C. 
Example:

```
Column B     Column C
Sam          Ziva
Jen          Tiva
Leo          Miva
```

So if name Sam exists in Column B I want to name it Ziva in Column C 
I tried it with simple IF statement but it only looks up for 1 field.

Comment: Have a look at VLOOKUP function.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work. Or you can replace the inner loop with a Vlookup per the comment.

```
dim idx1 as integer
dim idx2 as integer
dim idx3 as integer
idx1 = 2
idx3 = 1
while sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" + Cstr(idx1)).Value <> "" 
    idx2 = 2
    while sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" + Cstr(idx2)).Value <> ""
        if sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" + Cstr(idx1)).Value = sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" + Cstr(idx2)).Value then
            idx3 = idx3 + 1
            sheets("Sheet3").Range("C" + Cstr(idx3)).value = sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" + Cstr(idx1)).Value
        endif
        idx2 = idx2 + 1
    wend
    idx1 = idx1 + 1
wend
```